# How does variable decrement work in recursive functions

Tags: javascript, web, recursion, javascript-objects, development-environment

I know its a very beginner question
Here is scenario

```
Let number = 5; 
number - 1;
console.log(number);
```

it shows 5, why it does not show 4;

Comment: `number - 1` subtracts 1 from `number` but  nothing is being done with the result.

Comment: you must asign the value to your variable. number = number - 1;

Comment: I would advise against drastic changes to your questions. This question started with a simple variable assignment and changed into a question about recursion. This makes all the previous answers look somewhat incomplete. You can open multiple questions and link to old ones.

Comment: @Nickofthyme okey, I will add this a separate question

Answer (score 6):

You never changed the value of the variable. You can assign the decremented value like so:

```js
let number = 5; 
number = number - 1;
console.log(number);
```

The [decrement operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Decrement) can also be used.

```js
let number = 5; 
--number;
console.log(number);
```

OR

```js
let number = 5; 
number--;
console.log(number);
```

Answer (score 1):

Always assign the value, either in a new variable or in the same variable, if you want to see or use the change of your action.
if you assign it to a new variable then it would become:

```
Let number = 5; 
let newNumber = number - 1;
console.log(number); -- output 5
console.log(newNumber); --output 4
```

If you assign it to the same variable the it would become

```
Let number = 5; 
number = number - 1;
console.log(number); -- output 4
```

Answer (score 0):

Number -1 indeed is 4. But number still stays 5.
You need to write

```
number = number -1;
```

To be corect

Answer (score 0):

You are decrementing without assigning to your Variable `number - 1;`. Instead, there are two ways to decrement in your case,

Case 1:

> number = number - 1;

Case 2:

> number--;

Both will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Think like the computer would.

```js
let number = 5; 
number - 1;
console.log(number);
```

JavaScript will replace `number` in the second line with the value of the most recent variable assignment of `number` so essentially it would become...

```js
let number = 5; 
5 - 1; // this does no assignment so basically useless
console.log(5);
```

However, if you were to reassign the variable `number` it would look something like this...

```js
let number = 5; 
number = number - 1; // or number--
console.log(number);

// you can think of this like...
let number = 5; 
number = 5 - 1; // number is now 4
console.log(4);
```

---

### Update

With the new function, you added to this question it gets a bit more complicated because you are now dealing with [recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science)). Stepping through this as if we were the "computer" (aka debugging)...

```js
// actual function
function repeatStringNumTimes(string, times) {
  if (times < 0) 
    return "";
  if (times === 1) 
    return string;
  else 
    return string + repeatStringNumTimes(string, times - 1);
}
repeatStringNumTimes("abc", 3);

// Walking through this function from the first invocation above

// first function call
function repeatStringNumTimes(string, times) { // string = 'abc' and times = 3
  if (3 < 0) // false - thus skipped
    return "";
  if (3 === 1) // false - thus skipped
    return 'abc';
  else // run because all others were false/skipped
    // Note the code below will not return until the repeatStringNumTimes below returns
    return 'abc' + repeatStringNumTimes('abc', 3 - 1);
}

// second function call - first recursive call
function repeatStringNumTimes(string, times) { // string = 'abc' and times = 2 (i.e. 3 - 1)
  if (2 < 0) // false - thus skipped
    return "";
  if (2 === 1) // false - thus skipped
    return 'abc';
  else // run because all others were false/skipped
    // Note the code below will not return until the repeatStringNumTimes below returns
    return 'abc' + repeatStringNumTimes('abc', 2 - 1);
}

// third function call - second recursive call
function repeatStringNumTimes(string, times) { // string = 'abc' and times = 1 (i.e. 2 - 1)
  if (1 < 0) // false - thus skipped
    return "";
  if (1 === 1) // true - thus executed
    // This block is what is known as a "break case" see below
    return 'abc'; // returns 'abc' end of recursion!
  else // skipped because previous if statement returned 'abc'
    return 'abc' + repeatStringNumTimes('abc', 1 - 1);
}

// going back to the second function call, which we simplified to
function repeatStringNumTimes(string, times) { // string = 'abc' and times = 2
  return 'abc' + repeatStringNumTimes('abc', 2 - 1);
}

// but we know that the return value of `repeatStringNumTimes('abc', 2 - 1)` is just 'abc', thus we can say
function repeatStringNumTimes(string, times) { // string = 'abc' and times = 2
  return 'abc' + 'abc'; // or 'abcabc'
}

// going back to the first function call, which we simplified to
function repeatStringNumTimes(string, times) { // string = 'abc' and times = 3
  return 'abc' + repeatStringNumTimes('abc', 3 - 1);
}

// but we know that the return value of `repeatStringNumTimes('abc', 3 - 1)` is just 'abcabc', thus we can say
function repeatStringNumTimes(string, times) { // string = 'abc' and times = 3
  return 'abc' + 'abcabc'; // or 'abcabcabc'
}

// so the final value of this statement is 'abcabcabc' or...
repeatStringNumTimes("abc", 3); // returns 'abcabcabc'
```

What is a **break case**? A break case is used to end the recursion. Imagine your family tree and let's say you wanted to find your closest parental (great^x grandma/pa) relative that was named Jane/John. First you look at your parents, then you look at your parent's parents and so on until you fine a Jane/John. So in example our break case is when the name is Jane/John. Without a break case (or other breaks) your would result in an infinite loop.

Notice that the first if statement `if (times < 0)` was never executed, this is simply because the other break case (namely `if (times === 1)`) was triggered first which ended the recursion.

This is a very complex idea to explain/understand from just text examples and would implore you to look at this example to better understand recursion. https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/recursion-is-not-hard-858a48830d83/

Comment: I added an explanation of the new recursive code you posted.